# How to exract link to image "a href" & "class" in a html page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I have several images using the same line of code to refer to html image links on a page: `<a href="#" class="sh-mo__image" data-image="http://somejpgimage.jpeg">`
I would like to retrieve the link only but just can't seem to navigate beyond the `class` to the link.
Can anyone help?
Also I have "n" number of links which I would like to retrieve separately.

Comment: Are you accessing the image links via a url, or merely have a list of the `<a href`s to begin with?

Comment: There is a list of links within a webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what @D.Chel suggested using [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

```
>>> links = [x['data-image'] for x in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'sh-mo__image'})]
>>> links
['http://somejpgimage1.jpeg', 'http://somejpgimage2.jpeg']
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your are looking for something like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = ''' <a href="#" class="sh-mo__image" data-image="http://somejpgimage1.jpeg">
         <a href="#" class="sh-mo__image" data-image="http://somejpgimage2.jpeg"> '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

mylinks = []
for link in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'sh-mo__image'}):
    mylinks.append(link['data-image'])
```

Comment: This works although I would like to be able to put each link into a separate string? With your solution all the links are retrieved together. How would I create different strings for each n string ?

Comment: I updated the solution by adding saving the links in a list.

Comment: Amazing. I might be stating the obvious but for sake of completeness for anyone who reads this I would then call on each string in the index using `mylinks[0]`,`mylinks[1]`,`mylinks[2]` etc...

Comment: `for i in range(len(mylinks)):`